# React dropzone uploader file upload status is 'aborted' with multiple file upload

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

I'm trying to upload multiple files using React dropzone uploader.

```
import Dropzone from "react-dropzone-uploader";

const handleChangeStatus = async (fileWithMeta, status) => {
if(status === 'ready'){
const file = fileWithMeta.file
    // Some validation I am doing here
    // If all files are valid then I am calling one function
    // from parent through props. This function is setting state
    // value with selected files in parent component
    someFunctionfromProps(file);        
}}

<Dropzone
      getUploadParams={getUploadParam}
      onChangeStatus={handleChangeStatus}
      accept={fileTypesFormats.types}
      autoUpload={false}
      multiple={true}
    >
</Dropzone>

// Below function is at parent component
someFunctionfromProps= async (files) => {
 this.setState({
  files: [...this.state.files, files],
 });
};
```

Due to someFunctionfromProps file upload is getting "aborted", Only one file is getting
uploaded successfully, rest all files are getting "aborted".
Can someone help me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you figure anything out?